# Text overflow in css flexBox can be solved by simply add width:0, but why?

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.textEllipsis{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}

.wrapper .main,.sub{
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper .main{
    flex: 1;
    background: red;
}

.wrapper .main.widthConfig{
  width: 0;
}

.wrapper .sub{
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h3>right behavior</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main widthConfig">
    <div class="inner textEllipsis">
adfadfafasfafasdfasdfasdfasfafasdfasdfasdfasfafasdfasdfasdfasfafasdfasdfasdfasfafasdfasdfasdfasf
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    aaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
</div>
<h3>remove width: 0 get wrong behavior</h3>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inner textEllipsis">
adfadfafasfafasdfasdfasdfasfafasdfasdfasdfasfafasdfasdfasdfasfafasdfasdfasdfasfafasdfasdfasdfasf
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    aaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
</div>
```

In the snippet, I create an flexBox layout with `.wrapper` element.
And I add `flex:1` to the `.main` element, add a fixed width like `width: 100px` to the sub element.
In the child element of `.main` element I add some long text then the width of `.main` element is out of control.

But when I add `width: 0` to the `.main` element everything turn right.
Can any body tell me why?

Comment: This problem is more complex than just fiddling with flex properties: it is a subtle combination of problems between text-overflow and flex. I've been trying out different things with it, but can't explain why the `.main` box with `text-overflow` refuses to `flex-shrink`

Answer (score 2):

**Set `min-width: 0;` on the flex child**

Or set `min-width` to some actual value.
Without this, the flex child containing the other text elements won’t narrow past the "implied width" of those text elements.

According to a draft spec, the above text should not fully collapse when the flex container is resized down. Because subtitle has a width of 100%, the `min-width: auto` calculation that flex-box makes says that its container should be larger than we want.

This behavior is consistent across Chrome, Opera, and Firefox. Safari was shrinking/truncating even without the `min-width` (which is against the specs, I think).